# Blank Page Appearing. User not redirecting to login

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to authenticate the user before they can access any part of the website, but a blank page is appearing and the user is not redirecting.

Code:

Authentication Function:

```js
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export async function Authentication() {
  const loggedin = true;
  if (!loggedin) {
    throw redirect('/Login')
  }
}
```

Income Route : // problem is occurring here. This page is getting blank and not redirecting.

```
<Route
  path='Income'
  element={<Income />}
  loader={async() => {
    return await Authentication();
  }}
/>
```

Login Route:

```
<Route path='Login' element={<Login />} />
```

I was trying to authenticate a user before they can access any page of the website but a blank page appears and the user is unable to be redirected.

Comment: What router are you using? Route loaders only work with Data routers. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="Login" element={<Login/>} />
  <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
    <Route path="/Income" element={<Income />} />
    {/* Handle other Protected routes */}
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

inside `ProtectedRoute file`

```
//ProtectedRoute.js

import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import {Authentication} from "./your-file-path"

export const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await Authentication();
    })();
  }, []);

  return <></>;
};
```